# Telegram : How to Broadcast Message

Tags: telegram, php-5.6

We are planning to integrate Telegram with our project. The requirement is that when some event occurs, send a notification to a set of users. I have already created a test bot with telegram. My question is, is it possible to do it with bot ie sending a message to group of users. Or are there any other method to accomplish this.

We are using PHP for our project.

Answer (score 4):

Message can't send to multiple chat, even send one message pre request, there have [rate limit](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this).

You should try [channel](https://telegram.org/blog/channels) instead of private message, it support unlimited subscriber, and can post by any administrators (both human and bot).

Answer (score 2):

The best way is add your users to a group or channel, and then have your bot send the message to that group/channel.

But if you really need to send the message to each user, you may use telegram API.

Telegram Bot method is much easier to do the job. 
If you ended up doing the API (not the bot method) you may want to look at https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto which makes it easier to work with telegram API using php.